# Getting the wrong response from a GET request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm using BurpSuite to intercept the packages sent by http://sneakersnstuff.com. One of the first request is the following one:

```
GET /en/auth/view HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sneakersnstuff.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Mon, 16 Sep 2019 09:21:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d791d44829fdde014df45bb3e9671e8f71568625674; expires=Tue, 15-Sep-20 09:21:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.sneakersnstuff.com; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: max-age=2
Expires: Mon, 16 Sep 2019 09:21:16 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=a95faf1dfaa2eb32abd3fae494002bcf6b35ae93-1568625674-1800-AZVg4LQH3/RQ7cN285UiNAKrmsUPFe2LFKbgUPTpc5vE/VLUtX43OnvwnSwCj9Xk/0bwTRLNHEBfgInW0vXfsK0=; path=/; expires=Mon, 16-Sep-19 09:51:14 GMT; domain=.sneakersnstuff.com; HttpOnly
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 5171c4e1fd3dc2c2-FRA
Content-Length: 19712

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sneakersnstuff - Man or machine</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />

    <script>!function(a,e,t,c,n,g,s){a.GoogleAnalyticsObject=n,a.ga=a.ga||function(){(a.ga.q=a.ga.q||[]).push(arguments)},a.ga.l=1*new Date,g=e.createElement(t),s=e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],g.async=1,g.src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js",s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(window,document,"script",0,"ga"),ga("create","UA-1918066-1","auto"),ga("send",{hitType:"pageview",page:"/sns-cf-captcha",title:"CF Captcha",rayId:"5171c4e1fd3dc2c2",clientIP:"178.255.153.77"});</script>
    <style>blockquote,body,dd,dl,dt,fieldset,figure,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hr,html,iframe,legend,li,ol,p,pre,textarea,ul{margin:0;padding:0}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:400}ul{list-style:none}button,input,select,textarea{margin:0}html{box-sizing:border-box}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:inherit}audio,embed,img,object,video{height:auto;max-width:100%}iframe{border:0}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{padding:0;text-align:left}body{background:#fff;font-family:LL Circular,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:150%}h1,h2{font-weight:700}h1{font-size:32px;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:60px}h2{font-size:18px;margin-bottom:15px;margin-top:50px}p{margin-bottom:10px}.container{margin:80px auto 60px;max-width:40em}.catchpa{margin-bottom:30px}.dropdown{margin-top:30px}.dropdown-select{-webkit-appearance:none;background:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iNDgiIGhlaWdodD0iNDgiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTIzLjMgMjlMMTIgMTcuNmwxLjYtMS42IDkuNyA5LjggOS44LTkuOCAxLjYgMS42TDIzLjMgMjl6Ii8+PC9zdmc+) no-repeat;background-position:calc(100% - 1rem) 50%;background-size:1.5em;border:1px solid #000;font-size:1rem;line-height:1.3;padding:1rem 2.6rem 1rem 1rem}.dropdown-select:focus{outline:none}@media (max-width:700px){.container{padding:0 20px}}</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img id="logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI0MCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDkwIDQwIj4KCTxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0xNy41LDI4LjJIMy4yYy0wLjYsMC0xLjIsMC41LTEuMiwxLjJjMCwwLjYsMC41LDEuMiwxLjIsMS4yaDE0LjJjMi4xLDAsMy44LTEuNywzLjgtMy44UzE5LjUsMjMsMTcuNSwyM0gxNAoJCWMtNS4zLDAtOS42LTQuMy05LjYtOS42YzAtNS4zLDQuMy05LjYsOS42LTkuNmgxNC45YzIuOSwwLDUuNywxLjIsNy44LDMuM2MyLjEtMi40LDUtMy43LDguMi0zLjdjNiwwLDEwLjksNC45LDEwLjksMTAuOXYxMS4zCgkJYzAsMi44LDIuMyw1LjEsNS4xLDUuMWgxNC45YzIuMSwwLDMuOC0xLjcsMy44LTMuOGMwLTIuMS0xLjctMy44LTMuOC0zLjhoLTMuNGMtNS4zLDAtOS42LTQuMy05LjYtOS42YzAtNS4zLDQuMy05LjYsOS42LTkuNmgxMS45CgkJYzAuNywwLDEuMi0wLjUsMS4yLTEuMmMwLTAuNi0wLjUtMS4yLTEuMi0xLjJINzIuM2MtNi42LDAtMTEuOSw1LjQtMTEuOSwxMS45czUuNCwxMS45LDExLjksMTEuOWgzLjRjMC44LDAsMS41LDAuNiwxLjUsMS40CgkJYzAsMC44LTAuNiwxLjQtMS41LDEuNEg2MC44Yy0xLjUsMC0yLjctMS4yLTIuNy0yLjdWMTQuMkM1OC4xLDYuOSw1Mi4xLDEsNDQuOCwxYy0zLDAtNS45LDEtOC4zLDIuOWMtMi4yLTEuNi00LjktMi41LTcuNy0yLjVIMTQKCQlDNy40LDEuNCwyLjEsNi44LDIuMSwxMy40YzAsNi42LDUuNCwxMS45LDExLjksMTEuOWgzLjVjMC44LDAsMS40LDAuNiwxLjQsMS40QzE4LjksMjcuNSwxOC4yLDI4LjIsMTcuNSwyOC4yeiBNMjguOSw5LjZIMTQKCQljLTIuMSwwLTMuOCwxLjctMy44LDMuOGMwLDIuMSwxLjcsMy44LDMuOCwzLjhoMy41YzUuMywwLDkuNiw0LjMsOS42LDkuNnMtNC4zLDkuNi05LjYsOS42SDMuMmMtMC42LDAtMS4yLDAuNS0xLjIsMS4yCgkJYzAsMC42LDAuNSwxLjIsMS4yLDEuMmgxNC4yYzYuNiwwLDExLjktNS40LDExLjktMTEuOWMwLTYuNi01LjQtMTEuOS0xMS45LTExLjlIMTRjLTAuOCwwLTEuNS0wLjctMS41LTEuNGMwLTAuOCwwLjctMS41LDEuNS0xLjUKCQloMTQuOWMxLjUsMCwyLjcsMS4yLDIuNywyLjd2MjIuOWMwLDAuNiwwLjUsMS4yLDEuMiwxLjJzMS4yLTAuNSwxLjItMS4yVjE0LjZDMzQsMTEuOCwzMS43LDkuNiwyOC45LDkuNnogTTg0LjIsMTguMwoJCWMtMi4zLTIuMy01LjMtMy41LTguNC0zLjVoLTMuNGMtMC44LDAtMS40LTAuNy0xLjQtMS40YzAtMC44LDAuNi0xLjUsMS40LTEuNWgxMS45YzAuNywwLDEuMi0wLjUsMS4yLTEuMmMwLTAuNi0wLjUtMS4yLTEuMi0xLjIKCQlINzIuM2MtMi4xLDAtMy44LDEuNy0zLjgsMy44YzAsMi4xLDEuNywzLjgsMy44LDMuOGgzLjRjMi42LDAsNSwxLDYuOCwyLjhjMS44LDEuOCwyLjgsNC4yLDIuOCw2LjhjMCw1LjMtNC4zLDkuNi05LjYsOS42SDYwLjgKCQljLTYsMC0xMC45LTQuOS0xMC45LTEwLjlWMTQuMmMwLTIuOC0yLjMtNS4xLTUuMS01LjFjLTIuOCwwLTUuMSwyLjMtNS4xLDUuMXYyMy4zYzAsMC42LDAuNSwxLjIsMS4yLDEuMmMwLjYsMCwxLjItMC41LDEuMi0xLjIKCQlWMTQuMmMwLTEuNSwxLjItMi43LDIuNy0yLjdjMS41LDAsMi43LDEuMiwyLjcsMi43djExLjNjMCw3LjMsNS45LDEzLjIsMTMuMiwxMy4yaDE0LjljNi42LDAsMTEuOS01LjQsMTEuOS0xMS45CgkJQzg3LjYsMjMuNSw4Ni40LDIwLjUsODQuMiwxOC4zeiBNNDQuOSw3LjRjMy43LDAsNi44LDMuMSw2LjgsNi44djExLjNjMCw1LDQuMSw5LjEsOS4xLDkuMWgxNC45YzQuMywwLDcuOS0zLjUsNy45LTcuOQoJCWMwLTQuMy0zLjUtNy45LTcuOS03LjloLTMuNGMtMy4xLDAtNS41LTIuNS01LjUtNS41YzAtMy4xLDIuNS01LjUsNS41LTUuNWgxMS45YzAuNywwLDEuMi0wLjUsMS4yLTEuMmMwLTAuNi0wLjUtMS4yLTEuMi0xLjJINzIuMwoJCWMtNC4zLDAtNy45LDMuNS03LjksNy45czMuNSw3LjksNy45LDcuOWgzLjRjMy4xLDAsNS41LDIuNSw1LjUsNS41YzAsMy0yLjUsNS41LTUuNSw1LjVINjAuOGMtMy43LDAtNi44LTMuMS02LjgtNi44VjE0LjIKCQljMC01LTQuMS05LjEtOS4xLTkuMWMtMy41LDAtNi42LDItOC4xLDQuOWMtMS42LTIuNy00LjUtNC41LTcuOS00LjVIMTRjLTQuMywwLTcuOSwzLjUtNy45LDcuOXMzLjUsNy45LDcuOSw3LjloMy41CgkJYzMsMCw1LjUsMi41LDUuNSw1LjVjMCwzLTIuNSw1LjUtNS41LDUuNWwtMTQuMiwwYy0wLjYsMC0xLjIsMC41LTEuMiwxLjJjMCwwLjYsMC41LDEuMiwxLjIsMS4yaDE0LjJjNC4zLDAsNy45LTMuNSw3LjktNy45CgkJYzAtNC4zLTMuNS03LjktNy45LTcuOUgxNGMtMy4xLDAtNS41LTIuNS01LjUtNS41YzAtMy4xLDIuNS01LjUsNS41LTUuNWgxNC45YzMuNywwLDYuOCwzLjEsNi44LDYuOHYyMi45YzAsMC42LDAuNSwxLjIsMS4yLDEuMgoJCWMwLjYsMCwxLjItMC41LDEuMi0xLjJWMTQuMkMzOC4xLDEwLjQsNDEuMSw3LjQsNDQuOSw3LjR6Ii8+Cjwvc3ZnPgo=">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <select class="dropdown-select" id="select">
                <option selected>Choose another Language</option>
                <option value="en">English</option>
                <option value="it">Italian</option>
                <option value="fr">French</option>
                <option value="ja">Japanese</option>
                <option value="fi">Finnish</option>
                <option value="da">Danish</option>
                <option value="zh">Mandarin</option>
                <option value="vi">Vietnamese</option>
                <option value="es">Spanish</option>
                <option value="nl">Dutch</option>
                <option value="ko">Korean</option>
                <option value="pl">Polish</option>
                <option value="de">German</option>
                <option value="sv">Swedish</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Man or machine</h1>
            <p>Welcome to Sneakersnstuff</p>
            <p>Please complete a security check proving youâre not a robot in order to access the site.</p>
            <h2>Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?</h2>
            <p>Sneakerbots are creating a near-impossible situation for us to be able to do online releases in a fair
                way. We work hard to provide you with the best possible experience. Our bot fighter bot has determined
                that your browser signature might be of the automated sort. If youâre in fact a human being, we
                apologize and kindly ask you to please solve the captcha to continue using our site.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="captcha"><form class="challenge-form" id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_captcha" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="s" value="b4a9442887923bdc00fb2c491b9a7a611235eee2-1568625674-1800-AVNo9xc/ddLnLOUNdCs1uVkpStxbmQh+oNQLhBcVyEjmeBKgSpKD0Yb+RmZXekAjjVkCXqjqXsTDTXs551FEEBShnj5SBoM6RQT4OiE26KL3ZaRYWDYD5li0PXcfWOE6rR6/8fS92yRuYQRK5ntix90NP7sbtCBk2p5WzcQru20kt7WxcO8Z2WN8eBWAiQ/gG4OD32ONDj7kxuTsX97OqvL33lvDwxD0w/1vLDYkqni5"></input>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.challenge.js" data-type="normal"  data-ray="5171c4e1fd3dc2c2" async data-sitekey="6LfBixYUAAAAABhdHynFUIMA_sa4s-XsJvnjtgB0"></script>
  <div class="g-recaptcha"></div>
  <noscript id="cf-captcha-bookmark" class="cf-captcha-info">
    <div><div style="width: 302px">
      <div>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6LfBixYUAAAAABhdHynFUIMA_sa4s-XsJvnjtgB0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 302px; height:422px; border-style: none;"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 300px; border-style: none; bottom: 12px; left: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; right: 25px; background: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; border-radius: 3px;">
        <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
      </div>
    </div></div>
  </noscript>
</form>
</div>
    </div>
    <script>var langMarkup={en:"<h1>Man or machine</h1><p>Welcome to Sneakersnstuff</p><p>Please complete a security check proving youâre not a robot in order to access the site.</p><h2>Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?</h2><p>Sneakerbots are creating a near-impossible situation for us to be able to do online releases in a fair way. We work hard to provide you with the best possible experience. Our bot fighter bot has determined that your browser signature might be of the automated sort. If youâre in fact a human being, we apologize and kindly ask you to please solve the captcha to continue using our site.</p>",it:"<h1>Benvenuto in Sneakersnstuff</h1><p>Si prega di completare un controllo di sicurezza dimostrando che non sei un robot per accedere al sito.</p><h2>PerchÃ© devo completare un CAPTCHA?</h2><p>Gli sneakerbots stanno creando una situazione quasi impossibile per noi in modo da poter pubblicare le pubblicazioni online in modo corretto. Lavoriamo duramente per offrirti la migliore esperienza possibile. Il nostro bot bot per i combattenti ha stabilito che la tua firma del browser potrebbe essere del tipo automatico. Se sei effettivamente un essere umano, ci scusiamo e ti chiediamo gentilmente di risolvere il captcha per continuare a utilizzare il nostro sito.</p>",fr:"<h1>Homme ou machine</h1><p>Bienvenue chez Sneakersnstuff</p><p>Veuillez complÃ©ter une vÃ©rification de sÃ©curitÃ© prouvant que vous n'Ãªtes pas un robot afin d'accÃ©der au site.</p><h2>Pourquoi dois-je complÃ©ter un CAPTCHAâ¯?</h2><p>Les Sneakerbots crÃ©ent une situation quasi-impossible pour Ãªtre en mesure de faire nos sorties en ligne d'une maniÃ¨re Ã©quitable. Nous travaillons dur pour vous offrir la meilleure expÃ©rience possible. Notre bot fighter a dÃ©terminÃ© que la signature de votre navigateur pourrait Ãªtre du type automatisÃ©. Si vous Ãªtes en fait un Ãªtre humain, nous vous prions de bien vouloir rÃ©soudre le captcha pour continuer Ã  utiliser notre site.</p>",ja:"<h1>äººéã¾ãã¯ãã·ã¼ã³</h1><p>Sneakersnstuffï¼ã¹ãã¼ã«ã¼ãºã¨ã³ã¹ã¿ããï¼ã¸ãããã</p><p>ãå®¢æ§ãã­ãããã§ãªããã¨ãç¢ºèªããã¦ããã ãã¦ããã¾ãããµã¤ãããè¦§ã«ãªãåã«ãã»ã­ã¥ãªãã£ãã§ãã¯ããæ¸ã¾ããã ããã</p><h2>ãªãã­ã£ããã£ãå¿è¦ãªã®ã§ããï¼</h2><p>å½ç¤¾ãå¬æ­£ãªææ®µãç¨ãã¦ãªã³ã©ã¤ã³ãªãªã¼ã¹ãè¡ãããããSneakerbotsã¯æå³çã«å°é£ãªç¶æ³ãä½æãã¦ãã¾ãã å½ç¤¾ã¯ããå®¢æ§ã«æé«ã®ã«ã¹ã¿ãã¼ã¨ã¯ã¹ããªã¨ã³ã¹ããå±ãããããæ¥ãæ¹åãè¡ã£ã¦ãã¾ãã å½ç¤¾ã®ããããã¡ã¤ã¿ã¼ã­ãããã«ãããèªååããããã©ã¦ã¶ã®ã·ã°ããã£ã§ããå¯è½æ§ãããã¨å¤å®ããã¾ããã ãå®¢æ§ãäººéã§ããã£ãããå ´åã¯å¤§å¤ç³ãè¨³ãããã¾ããããå½ãµã¤ãããå©ç¨ããã ãå¿é ã®ãæç¶ãã¨ãªã£ã¦ããã¾ãããããååããã ãã¾ããããé¡ãç³ãä¸ãã¾ãã</p>",fi:"<h1>Ihminen vai kone</h2><p>Tervetuloa Sneakersnstuffille</p><p>Tee turvavarmennus osoittaaksesi ettet ole robotti ja vieraillaksesi sivustollamme.</p><h2>Miksi minun on tehtÃ¤vÃ¤ kuvavarmennus?</h2><p>Tennaribotit luovat lÃ¤hes mahdottoman tilanteen tehdÃ¤ verkkolanseerauksia reilulla tavalla. Teemme jatkuvasti tÃ¶itÃ¤ tarjotaksemme sinulle parhaan mahdollisen kÃ¤yttÃ¶kokemuksen. Botteja vastaan taisteleva bottimme on pÃ¤Ã¤tellyt, ettÃ¤ selaimesi jÃ¤lki muistuttaa automatisoitua tiliÃ¤. Jos kuitenkin olet ihminen, pahoittelemme ja pyydÃ¤mme sinua suorittamaan kuvavarmennuksen jotta voit jatkaa sivustomme kÃ¤yttÃ¶Ã¤.</p>",da:"<h1>Menneske eller maskine</h1><p>Velkommen til Sneakersnstuff</p><p>GenfÃ¸r venligst et sikkerhedstjek, der beviser, at du ikke er en robot, der prÃ¸ver at fÃ¥ adgang til hjemmesiden.</p><h2>Hvorfor skal jeg udfylde en CAPTCHA?</h2><p>Sneakerbots gÃ¸r det nÃ¦sten umuligt for os at lave online udgivelser pÃ¥ en retfÃ¦rdig mÃ¥de. Vi gÃ¸r vores bedste for at give dig den bedst mulige oplevelse. Vores botfighter-bot har fastslÃ¥et, at din browser-signatur kan vÃ¦re af den automatiserede slags. Hvis du rent faktisk er et menneske, undskylder vi og beder dig venligst om at udfylde captchaen for at fortsÃ¦tte med at bruge vores hjemmeside.</p>",zh:"<h1>äººæºè¯å«</h1><p>æ¬¢è¿æ¥å°Sneakersnstuff</p><p>è¯·å®æå®å¨æ£æ¥ï¼è¯ææ¨ä¸æ¯æºå¨äººåæ¹å¯è®¿é®ç½ç«ã</p><h2>ä¸ºä»ä¹å¿é¡»è¦å¡«åCAPTCHAï¼</h2><p>Sneakerbotså¯¼è´æä»¬å ä¹æ æ³ä»¥å¬å¹³çæ¹å¼è¿è¡çº¿ä¸åå¸ã æä»¬ä¸éä½åå°ä¸ºæ¨æä¾æåºè²çä½éªã æä»¬çåæºå¨äººç¨åºæºå¨äººå¤æ­æ¨çæµè§å¨ç­¾åå¯è½æ¯ä»¥èªå¨åæ¹å¼äº§ççã å¦ææ¨å®éä¸æ¯çäººï¼æä»¬åæ¨éæ­ï¼å¹¶æ³è¯·æ¨å¡«åCAPTCHAä»¥ä¾¿ç»§ç»­ä½¿ç¨æä»¬çç½ç«ã</p>",vi:"<h1>Con ngÆ°á»i hay mÃ¡y mÃ³c</h1><p>ChÃ o má»«ng báº¡n Äáº¿n Sneakersnstuff</p><p>Vui lÃ²ng hoÃ n thÃ nh kiá»m tra báº£o máº­t chá»©ng minh báº¡n khÃ´ng pháº£i lÃ  robot Äá» truy cáº­p trang web.</p><h2>Táº¡i sao tÃ´i pháº£i hoÃ n thÃ nh CAPTCHA?</h2><p>Sneakerbots sáº½ táº¡o má»t tÃ¬nh huá»ng gáº§n nhÆ° khÃ´ng thá» Äá» chÃºng tÃ´i cÃ³ thá» phÃ¡t hÃ nh trá»±c tuyáº¿n theo cÃ¡ch cÃ´ng báº±ng. ChÃºng tÃ´i ná» lá»±c Äá» mang láº¡i cho báº¡n tráº£i nghiá»m tá»t nháº¥t cÃ³ thá». Robot chá»ng láº¡i robot cá»§a chÃºng tÃ´i ÄÃ£ xÃ¡c Äá»nh ráº±ng chá»¯ kÃ½ trong trÃ¬nh duyá»t cá»§a báº¡n cÃ³ thá» lÃ  tá»± Äá»ng. Náº¿u báº¡n thá»±c sá»± lÃ  con ngÆ°á»i, chÃºng tÃ´i xin lá»i vÃ  mong báº¡n vui lÃ²ng giáº£i quyáº¿t captcha Äá» tiáº¿p tá»¥c sá»­ dá»¥ng trang web cá»§a chÃºng tÃ´i.</p>",es:"<h1>Hombre o mÃ¡quina</h1><p>Bienvenido a Sneakersnstuff</p><p>Para acceder a nuestra pÃ¡gina web, realiza la prueba de seguridad que demuestre que no eres un robot.</p><h2>Â¿Por quÃ© tengo que completar un CAPTCHA?</h2><p>Los Sneakerbots estÃ¡n creando una situaciÃ³n que casi no nos permite realizar lanzamientos en lÃ­nea de una manera justa. Trabajamos duro para ofrecerte la mejor experiencia posible. Nuestro bot que detecta robots ha determinado que la firma de tu navegador podrÃ­a tener un origen automÃ¡tico. Si no eres un robot, te pedimos disculpas y solicitamos amablemente que resuelves el captcha para seguir utilizando nuestra pÃ¡gina web</p>",nl:"<h1>Mens of machine</h1><p>Welkom bij Sneakersnstuff</p><p>Voltooi een veiligheidscheck om te bewijzen dat je geen robot bent, zodat je verder kunt naar de website. </p><h2>Waarom moet ik een CAPTCHA voltooien?</h2><p>Sneakerbots maken het voor ons bijna onmogelijk om op een eerlijke manier online releases aan te bieden. We werken er hard aan om je de best mogelijke ervaring te geven. Onze systeem tegen bots heeft vastgesteld dat je browser signature wellicht van de geautomatiseerde soort is. Ben je daadwerkelijk een persoon, bieden we je onze excuses aan en verzoeken we je vriendelijk de captcha op te lossen, zodat je onze site kunt blijven gebruiken.</p>",ko:"<h1>ì¬ë ëë ê¸°ê³</h1><p>Sneakersnstuff ë°©ë¬¸ì íìí©ëë¤</p><p>ì¬ì´í¸ì ì ìíê¸° ìí´ì ê·íê° ë¡ë´ì´ ìëì ì¦ëªíë ë³´ì ì²´í¬ë¥¼ ìë£í´ ì£¼ìê¸° ë°ëëë¤.</p><h2>ì ë´ê° CAPTCHAë¥¼ ìë£í´ì¼ í©ëê¹?</h2><p>Sneakerbotsë ë¹ì¬ê° ê³µì í ë°©ë²ì¼ë¡ ì¨ë¼ì¸ ì¶ìë¥¼ í  ì ìë ê±°ì ë¶ê°ë¥ì ê°ê¹ì´ ìí©ì ë§ë¤ê³  ììµëë¤. ë¹ì¬ë ê·íìê² ê°ë¥í ìµì ì ê²½íì ì ê³µíê¸° ìí´ ì´ì¬í ë¸ë ¥í©ëë¤. ë¹ì¬ì bot fighter botì ê·íì ë¸ë¼ì°ì  ìê·¸ëì²ê° ìëíë ìë¨ì¼ ì ìë¤ê³  ê²°ì íìµëë¤. ê·íê° ì¤ì ë¡ ì¬ëì¸ ê²½ì°, ê·íìê² ì¬ê³¼ëë¦¬ë©°, ë¹ì¬ì ì¬ì´í¸ ì´ì©ì ì§ìíë ¤ë©´ ìº¡ì°¨ë¥¼ í´ê²°í´ ì£¼ìê¸°ë¥¼ ë¶íëë¦½ëë¤.</p>",pl:"<h1>CzÅowiek czy maszyna</h1><p>Witamy w Sneakersnstuff</p><p>W celu uzyskania dostÄpu do strony musisz przejÅÄ przez kontrolÄ bezpieczeÅstwa i udowodniÄ, Å¼e nie jesteÅ robotem.</p><h2>Dlaczego muszÄ przechodziÄ weryfikacjÄ CAPTCHA?</h2><p>DziaÅalnoÅÄ sneakerbotÃ³w praktycznie uniemoÅ¼liwia nam udostÄpnianie online w uczciwy sposÃ³b. DokÅadamy wszelkich staraÅ, by zapewniÄ Ci jak najlepsze wraÅ¼enia z uÅ¼ytkowania. Nasz skrypt antybotowy ustaliÅ, Å¼e podpis z Twojej przeglÄdarki moÅ¼e mieÄ zautomatyzowany charakter. JeÅli w rzeczywistoÅci jesteÅ czÅowiekiem, przepraszamy i prosimy o przejÅcie przez weryfikacjÄ captcha, aby kontynuowaÄ korzystanie z naszej strony.</p>",de:"<h1>Mensch oder Maschine</h1><p>Willkommen bei Sneakersnstuff</p><p>Bitte fÃ¼hre eine SicherheitsprÃ¼fung durch, damit Du auf unsere Website zuzugreifen kannst, welche nachweist, dass Du kein Roboter bist.</p><h2>Warum muss ich ein CAPTCHA abschlieÃen?</h2><p>Sneakerbots schaffen eine nahezu unmÃ¶gliche Situation fÃ¼r uns Online-Releases auf eine faire Weise zu anzubieten. Wir arbeiten hart, um Dir das bestmÃ¶gliche Erlebnis auf SNS zu bieten. Unser Bot Fighter Bot hat festgestellt, dass Deine Browsersignatur mÃ¶glicherweise automatisiert ist. Wenn Du tatsÃ¤chlich ein Mensch bist, bitten wir Dich, das Captcha zu lÃ¶sen, um unsere Website weiterhin nutzen zu kÃ¶nnen.</p>",sv:"<h1>MÃ¤nniska eller maskin</h1><p>VÃ¤lkommen till Sneakersnstuff</p><p>VÃ¤nligen fyll i en sÃ¤kerhetskontroll som visar att du inte Ã¤r en robot fÃ¶r att komma Ã¥t webbplatsen.</p><h2>VarfÃ¶r mÃ¥ste jag slutfÃ¶ra en CAPTCHA?</h2><p>Sneakerbots skapar en nÃ¤stan omÃ¶jlig situation fÃ¶r att vi ska kunna gÃ¶ra online-slÃ¤pp pÃ¥ ett rÃ¤ttvist sÃ¤tt. Vi anstrÃ¤nger oss fÃ¶r att ge dig den bÃ¤sta mÃ¶jliga upplevelsen. VÃ¥r botfigher-bot har faststÃ¤llt att din webblÃ¤sar-signatur kan vara av den automatiserade sorten. Om du faktiskt Ã¤r en mÃ¤nniska ber vi om ursÃ¤kt samt Ã¶nskar att du lÃ¶ser CAPTCHA:n fÃ¶r att fortsÃ¤tta anvÃ¤nda vÃ¥r webbplats.</p>"};function getFirstBrowserLanguage(){var e,t,n,a=window.navigator,i=["language","browserLanguage","systemLanguage","userLanguage"],r=null;if(a.language)return 2<a.language.length?a.language.substr(0,a.language.length-3):a.language;if(Array.isArray(a.languages))for(e=0;e<a.languages.length;e++)if(n=(t=a.languages[e]).length,!r&&n&&(r=t),t&&2<n)return t.substr(0,t.length-3);for(e=0;e<i.length;e++)if(n=(t=a[i[e]]).length,!r&&n&&(r=t),t&&2<n)return t.substr(0,t.length-3);return r.contains("-")&&(r=r.substr(0,r.length-3)),r}function changeContent(){var e=document.getElementById("content"),t=getFirstBrowserLanguage();if("en"!==t&&langMarkup.hasOwnProperty(t)){var n=langMarkup[t];e.innerHTML=n}}function changeContentOnSelect(){var e=document.getElementById("content"),t=event.target.value;if(langMarkup.hasOwnProperty(t)){var n=langMarkup[t];e.innerHTML=n}}changeContent();var select=document.getElementById("select");select.addEventListener("change",changeContentOnSelect);</script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

My goal is to emulate this request using the python requests library and get the same response. None the less when I try to do so with the following code:

```
import requests

session = requests.session()

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
}
raw = session.get("https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/auth/view", headers= headers)
print(raw.text)
```

I get this response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | www.sneakersnstuff.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>


<!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/zepto.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.common.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->



</head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="cf-error-details-wrapper">
      <div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
        <h1>
          <span class="cf-error-type" data-translate="error">Error</span>
          <span class="cf-error-code">1020</span>
          <small class="heading-ray-id">Ray ID: 5371a03a1f24d621 &bull; 2019-09-16 07:46:12 UTC</small>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="cf-subheadline">Access denied</h2>
      </div><!-- /.header -->

      <section></section><!-- spacer -->

      <div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
        <div class="cf-columns two">
          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.</p>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div><!-- /.section -->

      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper">
  <p>
    <span class="cf-footer-item">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong>5371a03a1f24d621</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Your IP</span>: 171.235.151.87</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>

  </p>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
  window._cf_translation = {};


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can this output is different from the previous one. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: At least, you didnt sent the cookie with requests.

Comment: Please dont post images of code (=> http requests and responses are code too).

Comment: Looking at the response this might be due to the fact that the page uses Cloudflare's anti-bot page (or IUAM).
Bypassing this check is quite difficult to solve on your own, since Cloudflare changes their techniques periodically.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I'm very sorry I included the wrong image, the original request also didn't have cookies (I just updated my question)

Comment: @ToniSredanović Thank you very much for your comment, this is definitely due to Cloudflare. What suprises me is that this accures on the first request. I've tried disabling Javascript in my webbrowser and visiting the website and it works perfectly, so I don't understand why it wouldn't work with python requests.

Comment: I get the same response in the browser as with your python code. Probably Cloudflare's anti-bot protection got you already :)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I'm using a VPN and have changed it several times. What is particularly strange is that when I visit the webpage using the exact same VPN I get through (even in incognito mode). But is still get the cloudlfare thing when trying it out with python requests.

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, i think that you are trying to reach `https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/auth/view`, but in your code, you are only reaching `https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/` maybe that's the issue ?

**EDIT**:

after seeing comments about CloudFlare, maybe a workaround would be to use Selenium for python, and try to bypass the CloudFare authentication ?
here's the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Thank you very much, for your answer. I have also tried this out previously without any success (I just updated my question, with this in mind to prevent confusion)

Comment: @NazimKerimbekov I am encountering the same problem in R. Any work around on this?